# If line doesn't executed still object creation happens

Tags: java

When I read java docs about **Objects** class, I got confused about object creation. It says

> Unlike the method requireNonNull(Object, String), this method allows creation of the message to be deferred until after the null check is made

Here is the method body

```
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj, Supplier<String> messageSupplier) {
    if (obj == null)
        throw new NullPointerException(messageSupplier == null ?
                                       null : messageSupplier.get());
    return obj;
}
```

If **messageSupplier** is null, will object get created?

What about this code

```
public static <T> T requireNonNullElseGet(T obj, Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {
    return (obj != null) ? obj
            : requireNonNull(requireNonNull(supplier, "supplier").get(), "supplier.get()");
}
```

If **obj** is not null, will object creation happen?

Comment: I think that means that in `requireNonNull(Object, String)` you already have to have a string object somewhere before you perform a check. But in supplier case, you message might be created when `get` is called so that having this `obj == null` false you won't spend resources for creating and storing error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two methods use a similar technique for slightly different reasons.

First of all: a `Supplier<SomeType>` can be provided instead of a `SomeType` if it's unknown if the value will actually be required when the method is called. This can delay creation of the `SomeType` object until it's actually used, avoiding the time/memory cost of the creation when it's unnecessary.

Imagine for example a line like this:

```
requireNonNull(someParameter, "someParameter was not given for " + someOtherParameter);
```

If this line is executed the error message string (the second parameter) will *always* be constructed, no matter if `someParameter` is `null` or not. This is wasteful, we'd rather postpone creating the error message until it's actually needed. But writing `if (someParameter == null)` before this each time defeats the purpose of the method (since that's basically all it does), so we try to find a different way.

What if instead of providing an error message, we provide something that can *produce* the error message if and when it's really needed. That something is a `Supplier<String>`. One simple way to implement such a provider is with a lambda:

```
requireNonNull(someParameter, () -> "someParameter was not given for " + someOtherParameter);
```

Now the actual creation of the error string is only executed when `someParameter` is actually `null`.

Often this kind of optimization is minor, but in some cases (for example inside of a frequently called method) this kind of optimization can have real tangible benefits.

`requireNonNullElseGet` uses the same technique, but instead of a supplier for an error message it takes a supplier of an alternate value:

MyAwesomeObject foo = getSomeAwesomeObject();
MyAwesomeObject fooOrDefault = requireNonNullElseGet(foo, AwesomeObjectFactory::expensiveCreationMethod);

Here we use a method reference to point tell `requireNonNullElseGet` how to acquire a `MyAwesomeObject` if (and only if) `foo` is null.

If instead we did the (probably more readable)

```
MyAwesomeObject fooOrDefault = requireNonNullElse(foo, AwesomeObjectFactory.expensiveCreationMethod());
```

then `expensiveCreationMethod` would *always* be executed, no matter if the result is actually needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You read a bit too much in the javadoc.

This form of `requireNonNull` does not need a possible costly message String, i.e. composed of expression on variables. Instead a message supplier is passed, which might compose that String expression.

```
// requireNonNull(Object, String)
// Costly whether x is null or not: message used or not.
Objects.requireNonNull(x, "Error in " + map.get("x") + ", " + user.fullName());

// requireNonNull(Object, Supplier<String>)
// Only when x is null, a message is evaluated.
Objects.requireNonNull(x, () -> "Error in " + map.get("x") + ", " + user.fullName());
```

The documentation wants to express that the *message* will only be created when needed - with a messageSupplier.

The code looks a bit more complex, as passing `null` for messageSupplier is allowed.